How to specify a timeout in liquibase changeset transaction for postgres?
I am using liquibase docker with postgres 15 . runInTransaction set to default true.
Is there a way for me to specify a timeout for the transaction within which each statements are executed?
I have checked the documentation for the liquibase.properties file but could not identify anything relevant.
I know about setting statement_timeout and network timeout as mentioned here in --driver-properties-file. What I am looking for is a timeout at the changeSet transaction level?
For example
--changeSet1
SQL1
SQL2

I am looking for a timeout for the entire changeSet1. Is there a way to achieve this in liquibase?

There is no way to accomplish that by now as Liquibase does not call jdbc method setQueryTimeout anywhere in it's code.
Maybe you could open an issue at github requesting this enhancement?
